# Why is this select statement so slow?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

This select statement runs super slow. It takes over 10 seconds to complete the execution. Could be much longer but I can't know, because the connection to MySQL times out. That's a separate issue.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    f.id, f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (c.firstname)) children
FROM
    families f,
    children c,
    transactions t
WHERE
    f.companyid = 1170 AND f.id = t.familyid
        AND f.id = c.familyid
        AND t.transactiontype = 'P'
        AND t.taxdeductible = 'Y'
        AND YEAR(t.date) = 2017
        AND status = 'A'
        OR f.id = 9779432
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER BY name;
```

I do have indexes on families.companyid, children.familyid, transactions.transactiontype, transactions.taxdeductible and transactions.date.

Is there any reason why it would be doing a full table scan, despite my indexes?  Or is there other reason why this query runs slowly?

**EDIT:  To fill in some of the blanks as per the comments below:**

The children table has 17MB of data in 73,000 rows.

The families table has 6MB of data in 56,000 rows

The transactions table has 83MB of data in 980,000 rows.

**CHILDREN TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `children` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `familyid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `companyid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `picture` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stockpicture` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `firstname` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickname` varbinary(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `usecustomfee` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `usecustomproviderfee` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `customfee` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `customfeetypecode` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'MONTH',
  `customproviderfee` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `customproviderfeetypecode` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'MONTH',
  `usecustomchargeitem` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `customchargeitem` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dailyrate` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '55.00',
  `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `subsidynotrequired` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `subsidychildid` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subsidyapplicantid` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subsidynote` text,
  `waitingsince` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitingroom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitingtype` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'F',
  `preferredstart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrationdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `providerisparent` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `attendingschool` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `schoolname` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `liveswithmother` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `liveswithfather` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `liveswithother` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `otherguardian` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
  `note` text,
  `archived` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `priorityid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `onlineregistration` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `onlineregistrationaccept` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `registrationconfirmed` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `registrationconfirmeddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifieddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fullpart` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'F',
  `parttimedays` int(11) DEFAULT '10',
  `parttimedaystype` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'D',
  `parttimedaystypecode` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'MONTH',
  `program` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'daycare',
  `registrationnote` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrationnoteread` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `registrationsubsidy` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'noplan',
  `registrationsubsidydate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrationsubsidyamount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Familyid` (`familyid`),
  KEY `companyid` (`companyid`),
  KEY `startdate` (`startdate`),
  KEY `enddate` (`enddate`),
  KEY `roomid` (`groupid`),
  KEY `providerisparent` (`providerisparent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=93685 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**FAMILIES TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `families` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountnumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(245) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The account name will typically be the name of the parent responsible for payment',
  `motherid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fatherid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `notes` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  `financialaidrequired` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `intakesurveyid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `referralid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `registrationemailrequired` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `registrationemailsent` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `registrationemaildate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrationemailaddressfound` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitinglistemailrequired` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `waitinglistemailsent` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `waitinglistemaildate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitinglistemailaddressfound` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activationemailrequired` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `activationemailsent` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `activationemaildate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `activationemailaddressfound` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `companyid` (`companyid`),
  KEY `intakesurveyid` (`intakesurveyid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9803007 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**TRANSACTIONS TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `familyid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `transactiontype` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C' COMMENT '''C'' = Charge, ''P'' = Payment',
  `paymenttype` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '''DBT'' = Debit, ''CSH'' = Cash, ''CRE'' = Credit Card, ''CHQ'' = Cheque, ''MNY'' = Money Order,''EFT'' = Electronic Funds Transfer',
  `comment` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `reference` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargeitem` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `taxdeductible` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `payer` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'M',
  `createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifieddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Familyid` (`familyid`),
  KEY `Transaction Type` (`transactiontype`),
  KEY `Tax Deductible` (`taxdeductible`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1013472 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: 1) You are offtopic here; see instead the DBA website 2) you do not give enough information; such as volume of your tables (for small tables an index is never used)  3) "I lose my connection mysql" looks like a completely different problem, and should be addressed first 4) put parenthesis because X AND Y OR Z reads ambiguous, make sure it does what you want. 4) Use proper SQL syntax with INNER JOIN between tables

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant, as well as the result of the EXPLAIN. Also, note that `YEAR(t.date) = 2017` cannot use an index, but `t.date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'` can.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - "Lost connection" often means that the query ran too long.  Hence, this _is_ the right forum.  (Granted, the OP can't know that.)

Comment: @Strawberry - If `date` is `DATETIME`, then your suggestion leaves out most of New Year's Eve.

Comment: @RickJames I still do not agree. This is not a programming question. It is either a configuration problem (ServerFault or SuperUser) or a RDBMS problem (DBA). In no way does this fit a website about programming questions.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I see Optimization as a grey area betwen SE and SO.  I say that the 'right' solution will not be via configuration.  I get irritated at companies where programmers write sloppy code, then throw it over the wall to the DBA who tears his hair because of needing to reformulate the query.  This particular Question is _mostly_ solved by the programmer.

Comment: @RickJames SQL questions, even optimizing are for me better suited to DBA.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - OK.  I troll both dba.stackexchange and stackoverflow, so I pick up optimization issues even when put in the wrong (of those two) forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean this (which is how MySQL will interpret it):

```
(this AND that ...) OR (f.id=...)
```

Let's use `UNION` instead of `OR`.  (`OR` optimizes poorly.)

Let's also use the 'standard' `JOIN...ON` instead of 'commajoin'.

Let's not hide a column inside a function (`YEAR`); it inhibits use of an index.

You have already been berated for not saying which table contains `status`.  I see that Hamoon accidentally lost the fact(?) that `status` is in `f`.  I will assume that.

`DISTINCT` is not a function, so I removed the parens after it.

I'll pick `UNION DISTINCT` (slower, but matches `OR`'s semantics) instead of `UNION ALL` (faster, but might duplicate a row).

I'll move `children` to an outer `SELECT` to avoid some potential hiccups.

When `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` match, the query can run faster.  So, assuming `id` and `name` are are logically tied together, I think this will give you the same grouping and ordering:

```
GROUP BY name, id
ORDER BY name, id
```

Putting all my tips together:

```
SELECT  x.id, x.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.firstname) children
    FROM (
           ( SELECT  f.id, f.name,
                FROM  families f
                JOIN  transactions t  ON f.id = t.familyid
                WHERE  f.companyid = 1170
                  AND  t.transactiontype = 'P'
                  AND  t.taxdeductible = 'Y'
                  AND  t.date >= '2017-01-01'
                  AND  t.date <  '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                  AND  f.status = 'A'
           )
           UNION DISTINCT
           ( SELECT   f.id, f.name
                FROM  families f
                WHERE  f.id = 9779432
           ) 
         ) AS x
    JOIN  children c  ON x.id = c.familyid
    GROUP BY  x.name, x.id
    ORDER BY  x.name, x.id
```

You will need these indexes.  The column ordering is usually important.

```
f:  I assume it has PRIMARY KEY(id)
f:  (companyid, status)   -- in either order
t:  (familyid, transactiontype, taxdeductible, date)
t:  (transactiontype, taxdeductible, date, familyid)
c:  (familyid, firstname)
```

Some notes:

- I gave 2 indexes for `t` -- supply both, thereby letting the Optimizer decide whether to start with `f` or `t`.
- Some of the indexes are 'covering', thereby giving an extra boost.
- After the reformulation, `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` may be unnecessary.
- Multiple single-column indexes are often *not* as beneficial as a 'composite' (multi-column) index.

Comment: Yes, it is f.status.  Not sure why that was removed in the edit, although I originally did not have it in there so maybe that's why he removed it?

Comment: Wow! Your query returned results in 2.2 seconds as compared to my version which timed out after 10 seconds.  Although 2.2 seconds still seems a bit long, it's much much better than what I had, so thank you!

Comment: @Vincent - Hmmm... 2.2 does seem high.  How many rows in the resultset?  How many rows before the `GROUP BY` takes effect?  How big are the tables?  Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  Did I interpret the `AND/OR` correctly?

Comment: To others reading this Q&A -- This is a rather extreme example of how reformulating a query can be vital to performance.

Comment: Only 99 rows in the result set.

Comment: It's now returning in 0 seconds, but the first time I ran it it was 2.2 seconds.

Comment: I'm curious why you changed year(t.date) = 2017 to "t.date >= '2017-01-01' AND  t.date <  '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR"

Comment: @Vincent - "0 seconds" would be caching -- either the Query cache or I/O caching.  Run with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid the bogus QC timing.

Comment: @Vincent - My 5th paragraph briefly explains `YEAR`.  And both of my indexes on `t` takes advantage of the reformulation.

Comment: When I run it with SQL_NO_CACHE it returns in 0.31 seconds, 0.15 seconds, 0.16 seconds, etc.  So I think it's good.

Comment: @Vincent - Good.  Possibly the 2.2 seconds was when none of the data was cached in RAM.  0.31 had some cached; 0.15 and 0.16 had all cached.  I consider this to be the 'official' timing for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT 
    f.id, f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (c.firstname)) children
FROM
    families f,
    children c,
    transactions t
WHERE
    f.companyid = 1170 AND f.id = t.familyid
        AND f.id = c.familyid
        AND t.transactiontype = 'P'
        AND t.taxdeductible = 'Y'
        AND YEAR(t.date) = 2017
        AND f.status = 'A'
        OR f.id = 9779432
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER BY name;
```

to make sure the correct index is loaded

You say you "have indexes on", but you can only use 1 index per query, make `1` index for the query you need.

Also I'd recommend to never use multiples `from`'s, but use the `JOIN` statement rather to be able to target joined table indices and index against that

Comment: Only 1 index per query?  I'm not sure I understand.  Can you explain that comment a bit further please.

Comment: @Vincent - There is a rarely used technique called "index merge intersect" that can make use of 2 indexes.  But it is less efficient that building the equivalent 'composite' index (as I did in my Answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your tables schema. We need to check what indexes do you have.

Meanwhile  you can try to `JOIN` tables and remove `ORDER BY`. 
From what I see you have just one `f.id = 9779432`, so why should you order same value?

Check your `OR` condition, I've transformed it ti something that makes sense to me. Your initial statement with that broad OR means you need anything `YEAR(t.date) OR f.id = 9779432` does it make any sense to you?

```
SELECT 
    f.id, f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (c.firstname)) children
FROM
    families f
INNER JOIN children c
ON f.id = c.familyid
INNER JOIN transactions t
ON f.id = t.familyid
   AND t.transactiontype = 'P'
   AND t.taxdeductible = 'Y'
   AND YEAR(t.date) = 2017
WHERE
    (f.companyid = 1170 OR f.id = 9779432)
    AND f.status = 'A'

GROUP BY f.id;
```

Comment: Please use `ON` for saying how the tables relate, and `WHERE` for filtering.

Comment: tables schema added, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use 21st-century JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (c.firstname)) children
  FROM families f
  JOIN children c ON f.id = c.familyid
  JOIN transactions t ON f.id = t.familyid
 WHERE f.companyid = 1170 
   AND t.transactiontype = 'P'
   AND t.taxdeductible = 'Y'
   AND YEAR(t.date) = 2017
   AND status = 'A'
    OR f.id = 9779432
 GROUP BY f.id
 ORDER BY name;
```

Change `AND YEAR(t.date) = 2017` to `AND t.date >='2017-01-01 AND t.date < '2018-01-01'`. Why? The `YEAR()` form of that filter clause is not [sargeable](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28838/sargeable).

There's no way from your question to tell which table contains the `status` column, and it matters **hugely** for performance.  If it's `t.status`, then try creating a compound index on

```
 transaction(status, transactiontype, taxdeductible, date, familyid)
```

Then try a compound index on

```
 transaction(familyid, status, transactiontype, taxdeductible, date)
```

One of those should help a lot. Why? when satisfying your query on the `transaction` table, MySQL can random-access the index to the first eligible record: the one matching all the `=` criteria and having the lowest value `date`. Then  it can scan the index sequentially until it finds the last eligible date.

Use the index that performs best.

If the `status` column isn't in the `transaction` table take it out of that index.